# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.beeclear.english signatures do not match the previously installed version

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run my android app in physical device Samsung Galaxy A5 but get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.beeclear.english signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install /home/rua/Mycode/app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
i have searched for this error but didnt find answer and try restarting adb devices

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this mean you have already this app in your device

**uninstall** app if found in your device
**or**
**change** your **package**

and **install again**

it's Work ^^